# Why does touch the face make more likely to be infected?

Tags: human-biology, bacteriology, virology, pathology, infection

Why is it risky to touch the face although there is no direct contact with into the nose, eyes and mouth?

Is there any possibility that pathogens infect us from our facial skin?

Suppose we have viruses or bacteria on our hands and we touch the side of our nose with our hands.

Can these bacteria reach our noses by their own?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, each question should be posted separately — this improves the chances that you will get answers for each question and makes the answers more accessible for future users. ——— We also expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: Do you have evidence or a citation to prove your claim that it *is* risky to touch the face without direct contact with nose, eyes, or mouth?